# Drawing an adjustable grid on a movie with OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, overlay

I have a problem which I can not solve by myself.  Regarding my programming skills I am a beginner and I hope that you can help me to solve my problem!
I am running a Mac with OS X 10.9.4 and Xcode 5.1.1

First I wrote a program to draw grid on an image. The grid density can be adjusted with the Opencv GUI slider by changing the variable n.
I then tried to get the same thing on a movie instead of a picture.
Unfortunately I didn’t succeed with this task. To get the frames of a movie I found a piece of code on the web. The frames of the pictures are captured within an infinite loop: while(1)

When I put my draw loop (for drawing grid lines) and on_trackbar function (for calling the slider) outside of the while(1) loop, I have the impression that the program is trapped within my infinite loop and it never calls the trackbar function.
When I put my function within the infinite loop, the movie is appearing but no slider and grid are showing up.
Unfortunately I can’t create a transparent image (Scalar(255,255,255,255)) and then add up the two images.
The size of the input arguments do not match (different amount of channels I believe?)

Here is my code:

```
//program to draw a nxn grid on a movie
//variable n can be adjusted with the Opencv GUI slider


#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global Variables
const int n_slider_max = 9; ///highest density grid will be max+1/max+1 = 10/10
int n_slider;

/// Function header
void MyLine( Mat img, Point start, Point end );
void on_trackbar(int, void*);

int main( void ){

/// Initialize values
  n_slider = 0;

/// 2. Create Trackbar
  char TrackbarName[100];
  sprintf( TrackbarName, "N range [1,10]");

  createTrackbar( TrackbarName, "Myvideo", &n_slider, n_slider_max, on_trackbar );

/// Show some stuff
 on_trackbar( n_slider, 0 );

  waitKey( 0 );
  return(0);
}

/// Function Declaration

/**
 * @function MyLine
 * @brief Draw a simple line
 */
void MyLine( Mat img, Point start, Point end )
{
  int thickness = 2;
  int lineType = 8;
  line( img,
    start,
    end,
    Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ),
    thickness,
    lineType );
}

/**
 * @function on_trackbar
 * @brief Callback for trackbar
 */
void on_trackbar( int, void* )
{


  VideoCapture cap("movie.avi");

    //get width and height of movie frames
    int frame_width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int frame_height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);


  namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"



    // Movie Loop: loop to read video frames and display them in a window
loop:while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
            break;
        }

        /// Create an empty black image with the dimensions of the frame
        // when I try to create an transparent image with Scalar (255,255,255,255)
        // I get an error message telling me that the size of the input arguments do not match.
        Mat grid_image = zeros( frame_height, frame_width, CV_8UC3 );

        //Draw loop
        for(int i=1; i<n_slider+1; ++i)
        {//vertical lines
            MyLine( grid_image, Point( grid_image.cols*i/(n_slider+1), 0 ), Point(grid_image.cols*i/(n_slider+1), grid_image.rows ) );

            //horizontal lines
            MyLine( grid_image, Point( 0, grid_image.rows*i/(n_slider+1) ), Point( grid_image.cols,grid_image.rows*i/(n_slider+1) ) );
        }

        //Create a new image for mixing
        Mat mixed_image;


        addWeighted(grid_image,0.2,frame,0.8,0.0, mixed_image);
        imshow("MyVideo", mixed_image); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window


        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }



}
```

Thanks for reading my post and I hope you can help me.

Cheers

Krunch

Comment: Are You absolutely sure that this code was working with camera input? Code looks like there was couple of bits randomly put inside. Try keeping main loop in main function, and on_trackbar modify ONLY the variables controlling the grid. Then, waitKey() will need to be called in the main loop to trigger all the GUI interactions.

Comment: I added a waitKey(0) at the the end of my main function (see working code below). It is called only once. How can it trigger all the GUI interactions? [waitKey(30) == 27 is only used to stop the program if esc key is pressed]

Comment: From [OpenCV waitKey() documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey):"Note This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes care of event processing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_trackbar()` function is a callback. It gets called only when you make a change to the trackbar position. So according to your code, once you make a change, it should never exit from the callback.

What your code section should look like is:

```
void on_trackbar()
{

//modify the value of n (possibly global)

}


int main()
{

  VideoCapture cap(..);
  createTrackbar(..);

  while(1)

  ..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help.

I restructured my code following your advice. My program is now running!
The code is more concise. Instead of doing a superposition of images, the program is now directly drawing the gridlines onto the camera frames.

Here is the new code:

```
//Program to draw a nxn grid on a movie
//The grid density can adjusted with the Opencv GUI slider


#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global Variables
const int n_slider_max = 9; ///highest density grid will be max+1/max+1 = 10/10
int n_slider;

/// Function header
void MyLine( Mat img, Point start, Point end );
void on_trackbar(int, void*);

int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    /// Initialize values
    n_slider = 0;


    //Capture the movie given as a command line argument
    VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);


    //create a window called "Video"
    namedWindow("Video",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    /// 2. Create Trackbar
    char TrackbarName[100];
    sprintf( TrackbarName, "N range [1,10]");

    createTrackbar( TrackbarName, "Video", &n_slider, n_slider_max, on_trackbar );


    // Movie Loop: loop to read video frames and display them in a window
    while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
            break;
        }


        //Draw loop
        for(int i=1; i<n_slider+1; ++i)
        {//vertical lines
            MyLine( frame, Point( frame.cols*i/(n_slider+1), 0 ), Point(frame.cols*i/(n_slider+1), frame.rows ) );

            //horizontal lines
            MyLine( frame, Point( 0, frame.rows*i/(n_slider+1) ), Point( frame.cols,frame.rows*i/(n_slider+1) ) );
        }


        //Show the movie
        imshow("Video", frame);


        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }

    waitKey( 0 );
    return(0);

}

/// Function Declaration

/**
 * @function MyLine
 * @brief Draw a simple line
 */
void MyLine( Mat img, Point start, Point end )
{
    int thickness = 1;
    int lineType = 8;
    line( img,
         start,
         end,
         Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ),
         thickness,
         lineType );
}

/**
 * @function on_trackbar
 * @brief Callback for trackbar
 */
void on_trackbar( int, void* )
{

}
```